# count rows with same id and print

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this table 'users_photos'. It contains 38k rows with user pictures. Every row contains id, userid and link to the photo. So if a user have 3 pictures, that user id will show in 3 rows in the database.

What I want to do is count the number of users with 1 picture in the database, 2 pictures in the database etc.

UPDATE: I have now the following code

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*), count_users from (SELECT u_id, count(*) as count_users FROM users_photos group by u_id) temp group by count_users");
    $sql->data_seek(0);
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "".$fetch."  = " . $row['count_users'] . "\n<br>";
}
```

This prints the users that have 1 picture and up to 8. Not how many but only shows that in the database there is users that have 1 picture, 2 pictures etc. Now I need to figure out how to print the total users that have 1 picture etc.

Anyone have any tips? thanks on behalf!

Comment: Try this `select count(*), count_users from (SELECT u_id, count(*) as count_users FROM users_photos group by u_id) temp group by count_users`

Comment: @bassxzero I think the select `u_id` in the subquery is unnecessary

Comment: and how do i print that? simply echo the $sql?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Comment: @bassxzero so I managed to make it print 1-8 (so I guess there is users that have 1 picture and up to 8 pictures) using example 2 in the link. But how do I make it print the total number of users that have 1 picture etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update Your Query With This**

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*),u_id as 'count_users' FROM users_photos group by u_id");
```

Comment: but how do I print the result? tried looking at php.net -> quick statements, but couldnt figure out how to print

Comment: So turns out I could just put in the sql code in my database and it prints the result. Which works for me! thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Sql Query:**

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*),u_id as 'count_users' FROM users_photos group by u_id");
```

---

You Can Print like this

---

```
// After Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT count(*),u_id as 'count_users' FROM users_photos group by u_id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - count_users" . $row["count_users"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$sql = 'SELECT u_id, count(*) AS count_users FROM users_photos GROUP BY u_id';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo 'User id: ' . $row['u_id'] . ' Count: ' . $row['count_users'] . '<br>';
}
```

Keep in mind this is just a basic example. In a real world application there is more to do such as checking for errors.